# How to stack Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Sorry for my Bad English. But there is no problem with reading.

If I add a fragment, the previous one will disappear.

I don't know what the problem is.

When I press the back key, the The main activity ends.

The Fragment that I want to add to the main activity

```
 holder.post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("postid", post.getPostid());
            editor.apply();
            ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new PostDetailFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

Main Activity

I think...

Something must have been wrong with BottomNavigationView or onBackPressed().

```
 BottomNavigationView bottom_navigation;
Fragment selectedfragment = null;
private long time = 0;
public static Activity _MainActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    _MainActivity = MainActivity.this;

    bottom_navigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);



    Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (intent != null){
        String publisher = intent.getString("publisherid");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("profileid", publisher);
        editor.apply();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new ProfileFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.time >= 2000) {
        this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press back again to leave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.time < 2000) {
        finish();
    }
}

public BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        selectedfragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_search:
                        selectedfragment = new SearchFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_add:
                        selectedfragment = null;
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_heart:
                        selectedfragment = new NotificationFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_profile:
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("profileid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        editor.apply();
                        selectedfragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        break;
                }
                if (selectedfragment != null) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedfragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();                                 }

                return true;
            }
        };
```

}

Comment: Can you post the logcat from the crash?

Comment: I'm sorry.  There's no crash.

Comment: Just replace `beginTransaction().replace` with `beginTransaction().add`

Comment: If I use add, it looks strange because it overlaps with the old one. And The main activity ends.

Comment: Can you describe your expected behaviour? When you press the back key at the Fragment, do you expect the fragment to pop and reveal the last fragment? Or do you expect `"Press back again to leave"` appear?

Comment: I expect only remove last fragment..